# Year/Month/Date input

Tags: focus

I'm looking for some simple code

<input type="text" name="year" maxlength="4">

<input type="text" name="month" maxlength="2">

<input type="text" name="day" maxlength="2">

so when I finish typing the year, it will focus on month then day and stop.

I can't seem to find the right search words in Google. I,m sure this has been done by a 1000 people.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code; I used jQuery to accomplish this.  You'll need to include jquery in the same directory and also add the "id" attribute to each of your inputs.

```
<script src='jquery.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type="text" name="year" id="year" maxlength="4">

<input type="text" name="month" id="month" maxlength="2">

<input type="text" name="day" id="day" maxlength="2">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#year").bind( 'keypress', function(e) {
        if( $("#year").val().length >= 4 ) 
            $("#month").focus();
    });
    $("#month").bind( 'keypress', function(e) {
        if( $("#month").val().length >= 2 ) 
            $("#day").focus();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. What is jquery? First time I've heard of it.
I reduced it to 3 so when I type a digit for a month it moves.
if( $("#year").val().length >= 3 ) 
Awesome, thanks. Downloaded jquery. It works.